# Como calcular valor de uma célula somente o que exceder a outra

Tags: microsoft-excel, phpexcel

Qual fórmula procederia para calcular um valor acima de um determinado número?

Exemplo: Área a calcular acima de 2,00M². O valor da multiplicação deu 2,75.

Como faço para registrar na célula somente o 0,75 - e na mesma fórmula houver um valor menor que 2M² e não ficar em quantidade negativa. Ex: valor de 0,40 = -1,60.

Answer (score 2):

É só fazer uma condição se for maior que 2,00 faça a diferença, senão fica o valor que está:

```
A1 = 2,75
B1 = SE(A1>2;A1-2;A1)
B1 = 0,75
```

Veja mais detalhes sobre a função `SE` [aqui](https://support.office.com/pt-pt/article/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-SE-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2?ui=pt-PT&rs=pt-PT&ad=PT).